# What's up with Big Alice's piercings?

Tags: snowpiercer, snowpiercer-2020

In the second season of the Netflix series *Snowpiercer*, we meet Alex. Alex is an engineer aboard Big Alice, and is revealed to be

> Melanie Cavill's daughter, thought to be dead for 7 years.

We see that Alex has a [lot of ear piercings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8bgl.png), more so than I would think normal for a 17 year old (even one stuck on a train), and this is just one ear.

Then in *Episode 4: A Single Trade*, I noticed that two other people were similarly heavily pierced.
One person who has [a nose ring, and a lip ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8oY.png), along with [several earrings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0toS.png), and a second who has [several earrings, and a nose ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGNmg.png).

I didn't note anyone aboard Snowpiercer being so heavily pierced. Is there an in-universe answer as to why the occupants of Big Alice are more pierced than the occupants of Snowpiercer? If not, is there an out-of-universe answer?

Comment: Maybe they're snowpiercings

Comment: Are you open to the possibility that the answer lies in your own impressions about piercings? These all appear mundane to me. Perhaps especially among youthful people.

Comment: At a guess, possibly they live in a post-apocalyptic society in which piercings are somewhat more common than now? Multiple piercings were not terribly uncommon even in [2017](https://www.statista.com/statistics/259704/number-of-piercings/), but those are unusual numbers. I count 7 or so earrings in the third photo, plus a nose ring. That would be 8 or 15 if they have the same setup on their other ear. In the second photo, I count 7 ear piercings, several eyebrow piercings, and a nose and lip piercing, which could be over 20 if both ears/brow. That would put them in the top 1% in modern times.

Comment: @indigochild - There is a clear difference between the amount found on Snowpiercer vs Big Alice. Besides I have several piercings myself, and only noticed the lack of earrings on Snowpiercer after seeing how awesome they look on people from Big Alice